# pyqtgraph not working in ROS Kinetic

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am having issues with ROS Kinetic and pyqtgraph. After installation of pyqtgraph and rqt_plot fails to run with the following error

RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore and PyQt5.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class

Has anybody encountered this and found a solution to the problem?

Thanks,
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236924/pyqtgraph-not-working-in-ros-kinetic/) by [maxikrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/15456/maxikrie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure to install pyqtgraph using the latest github code. The .deb installer does not install correctly.

Download github branch.

cd into extracted folder.

run:
python setup.py install

Now try running and setting the pyqtgraph option in rqt_plot.

Hope this helps, Eric H.

---

Originally posted by [bad_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/27666/bad_robot/) with karma: 26 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxikrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/15456/maxikrie/) on 2016-08-05**:
Thanks, this helped immediately.

**Comment by [maxikrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/15456/maxikrie/) on 2016-11-29**:
Unfortunately it is broken again, does anybody know how to fix it?

**Comment by [robopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26642/robopo/) on 2017-03-19**:
Downloaded from git, installed (no errors), not working... Please anybody else?

**Comment by [Curt](https://answers.ros.org/users/12666/curt/) on 2018-04-30**:
still works, uninstall the package pyqtgraph from the system then install from the git repo.